# Is it possible to hide some options from choice list in twig in from symfony select type form element?

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I have a form and making a select list element as follows-

```
$builder->add('location', 'choice', array(
     'empty_value' => 'Select',
     'choices' => array(0 => 'Brazil', 1 => 'USA', 2 => 'Europe'),
     'label' => 'select your choice',
));
```

Now I don't want the second option to come in dropdown, I would set it in js on basis of some other conditions so dropdown should show only two options i.e. Brazil and Europe, Is it possible to do so in symfony version 2.3?

Comment: So do you want to do that in Symfony(PHP) or JS?

Comment: I want in symfony

Comment: What exactly stops you from doing that? On what condition would you like to make this decision?

Comment: @JakubMatczak I don't want to do this in JS, I want some symfony solution for this, there is an option called choice_attrs through which I could achieve this but that is not available in version 2.3

Answer (score 0):

The only idea I come across is to create your own `form_theme` and then filter a thing you want to hide.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes